# Get the number of distinct elements in a submatrix

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, distinct-values

This was [a problem from the December 2013 CodeChef Challenge](http://www.codechef.com/DEC13/problems/RECTQUER) and the contest has ended.

**Problem Statement:**

> **Input:** Square matrix of order n and a query which will denote the submatrix.
>
> `(x1, y1, x2, y2)`
>
> `x1, y1` denotes the upper left and `x2, y2` denotes the lower right end of submatrix.
>
> **Output:** Number of distinct elements in this submatrix.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> - Time limit = 1 sec
> - 1 ≤ N ≤ 300
> - 1 ≤ Q ≤ 10^5
> - 1 ≤ Ai,j ≤ 10
> - 1 ≤ X1 ≤ X2 ≤ N
> - 1 ≤ Y1 ≤ Y2 ≤ N

This is what I've tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
  //clrscr();
  int a[300][300], test[100000], count[10], m, n, c, j, p, q, r, s;
  long qu, re, i;

  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }
  }

  scanf("%ld", &qu);
  for (re = 0; re < qu; re++)
  {
    c = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      count[i] = 0;
    }

    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &p, &q, &r, &s);
    for (i = (p-1); i < r; i++)
    {
      for (j = (q-1); j < s; j++)
      {
        m = a[i][j];
        count[--m]++;
      }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      if (count[i] != 0)
      {
        c++;
      }
    }
    test[re] = c;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < qu; i++)
  {
    printf("%d\n", test[i]);
  }

  //getch();
  return 0;
}
```

But I got a TLE(time limit exceeded) error.

It has to do something with cumulative frequency of each number.

Can someone suggest an efficient algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Your code should be properly indented to make it easier for us to read it. Also, you should use more meaningful variable names, not one or two letter variable names.

Comment: It seems that you are assuming that the matrix will only contain the integers 0 to 9. But this is nowhere stated in your question!

Answer (score 1):

Initialize and keep track of a hash map.

Iterate through the entries of the sub-matrix, and for each entry,

- check if it is in the hash map already;
- if not, increment `total_distinct_entries` by 1, and add this entry to the hash map.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table.

**Edit:** See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_data_structure, specifically the section on implementations.  In C++, a `std::set` data structure is available in the standard library.

Comment: A hash map would actually be **less** efficient than what OP currently does. Note that the code in the question only loops through the target area once, performing 2 very simple lines of code.

Comment: @Dukeling That's true; OP's "solution" presumes that the matrix entries are in the range `[1,10]`, which he didn't state in the original post.  I agree that his brand of solution is faster than a hash map with this added constraint, but with this added constraint it seems like there can't really be a solution much better than the one he has, EXCEPT...

Comment: (continued) ...that it seems (reading backward from his solution) like the problem is really that he will be given some *collection* of sub-matrices of *the same* matrix, and the way he is expected to optimize a solution is to cache information between iterations.  Of course there is no mention of any of this in his problem description.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

(working with 1 based index)

First try:

Do brute force, storing the count of each number in a count array as the question poster has given, but this will definitely time out on a lot of test cases.

Second:
Since we know that the entries can only be upto 10 We can try to store the number of times each number appears in the submatrix (1,1) to (i,j).
Suppose this matrix is Q. Q[i][j][k] gives the number of times k appears in the i,j submatrix.

This can be computed efficiently as follows:

```
for i from 1 to n
    for j from 1 to n
       for k from 0 to 10
            Q[i][j][k] = Q[i-1][j][k] + Q[i][j-1][k] - Q[i-1][j-1][k]
       Q[i][j][A[i][j]]++
```

This can be done in O(n^2 * (k)) time. Since k is less than 10 it's pretty efficient.

Now answering the queries is pretty easy:

For a query (x1,y1) - (x2,y2)

```
int count[10]
for k from 0 to 10
   // x is row and y is column
   count[k] = Q[x2][y2][k] - Q[x1-1][y2][k] - Q[x2][y1-1][k] + Q[x1-1][y1-1][k]
```

This answers all the queries in O(k) time. Since k is from 0 to 10. It's well within the time limits.

Comment: @gustav-bertram there is no assumption here, I didn't want to spoil the complete problem for him. codechef.com/viewsolution/3102585

Comment: Since the original poster's solution is not sufficiently optimized for an `N=300 Q=100000 (X1,Y1,X2,Y2)=(1,1,300,300)` input, would you mind posting yours and how it works?

Comment: This is a very impressive answer! Thank you for posting it. About spoiling the problem - On Stack Overflow you shouldn't do lazy people's work *for* them, but there isn't any concept of spoiling a problem for someone. If you can easily answer a problem fully, you should. It is intended to help not only the original questioner, but everyone who reads the question and answer after today.